# Where are the experience level breakpoints and current total displayed?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is there somewhere where I can view the current amount of experience my character has earned? I understand my current *level* is displayed in the Squad menu, but I want to know what my current *experience total* amounts to.

As a corollary question, is the amount of experience required for each level available to view somewhere? As in, 100 exp. for level 1, 250 exp. for level 2, 475 exp. for level 3, etc.

Basically, I want to know where I stand when it comes to leveling instead of seemingly arbitrarily leveling up. It just seems silly to have all these "+X EXP!" messages appear without any context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't show you exact numbers, but if you go to the squad menu and view your character, next to your current level it will show you a progress bar of how far along you are. It seems the best that you can do is see a number come in, then flip over to see how much your bar jumped. You can use this as a gauge for how close you're getting

[image]

Ultimately, you're better off just ignoring the actual numbers and simply enjoying the ride. Since there really aren't any mechanics in place to grind experience points, the actual numbers end up not mattering much.